# Determine if PostgreSQL query ran from disk or from memory cache?

Tags: performance, postgresql, caching, postgresql-9.1

In the Postgres command line client psql, is there a way to tell if a query runs from disk or from the memory cache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A query never runs "from disk" or "from cache". The query itself is always in memory.

But if you mean you want to find out if the data was retrieved from the shared buffers or directly from the filesystem then you can use

```
explain (analyze on, buffers on, verbose on) 
select ....
```

the execution plan will then show you how many block where fetched from the shared buffers and how many from the filesystem. Note that a "read" from the filesystem might actually be returned from a cache as well as the file system manages its own cache (something Postgres relies on).